# How to Reformat Mac with no disk

Tags: mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reinstalling Mac OS X without original disc](https://superuser.com/questions/484507/reinstalling-mac-os-x-without-original-disc/484527#484527)
>   [Restore MacBook Pro to factory settings without disc](https://superuser.com/questions/157655/restore-macbook-pro-to-factory-settings-without-disc)

I have a MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion (10.8.2) on it, (I've updated the Mac Digitally), I'm passing this Mac to a colleague and wonder how I go about re-formatting?

I have no disks as the Mac didn't come with any when we bought it. (From Apple)

Comment: Check [Lauri Ranta's answer](http://superuser.com/a/471935/48078) for the proper procedure with 10.8, or [my answer here](http://superuser.com/a/484527/48078) for an approach using [Lion DiskMaker](http://blog.gete.net/lion-diskmaker-us/). For the latter you won't have to have internet access while re-installing, only for downloading the installer before.

Comment: My actual end result was to hold CMD+R while rebooting and do the re-install from there.